# Obtener registros dentro de un rango de fechas en Joomla

Tags: php, joomla3

Necesito ejecutar una query en Joomla (3.5.1) que seleccione todos los registros cuya fecha no esté entre su propia fecha y 5 días después.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que *a.DateSubmitted* es igual a "2016-07-10 00:00:00". Quiero seleccionar ese registro sólo si a.DateSubmitted no está entre **2016-07-10 00:00:00** y **2016-07-15 00:00:00**.

¿Cómo hago eso?

Tengo lo siguiente, pero no funciona. El navegador me devuelve sólo esto: "Array ( )", nada más.

```
$db    = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query
    ->select('a.SubmissionId, a.DateSubmitted, b.SubmissionId, b.FieldName, b.FieldValue')
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__rsform_submissions', 'a'))
    ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__rsform_submission_values', 'b') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('a.SubmissionId') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('b.SubmissionId') . ')')
    ->where($db->quoteName('a.DateSubmitted') . ' NOT BETWEEN \'' . $db->quoteName('a.DateSubmitted') . '\' AND \'' . date( $db->quoteName('a.DateSubmitted') , strtotime('+5 day')) . '\'   ');
```

Comment: Asumo que utilizas `$db->loadObjectList();` ? con el debug de joomla puedes ver todas las consultas que se hacen a la base de datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No me queda muy claro de donde obtienes `a.DateSubmitted`, independiente de donde lo obtengas la idea es la misma, estás usando el método `quoteName` que es para nombres de campos, si quieres agregarle quotes a las fechas debes usar el método `quote`, y estás haciendo el between con campos de texto, no con fechas reales:

```
// aunque la fecha asumo que la obtienes de otro lugar
$dateSubmitted = JFactory::getDate('2016-07-10 00:00:00');

// ... modificar el where de la query 
->where($db->quoteName('a.DateSubmitted') . ' NOT BETWEEN ' . $db->quote($dateSubmitted) . ' AND ' . $db->quote($dateSubmitted->add(new DateInterval('P5D')));
```

Comment: Gracias por responder amigo @Shaz. La idea es esta: uso RSForm para los formularios. Una tabla guarda la fecha de submission, y la columna sería esta: a.DateSubmitted. La fecha tiene el formato **2016-07-10 00:00:00**. Por esta razón no puedo obtener la fecha como pusiste en tu ejemplo. La fecha la obtengo de la BD, y a esa debo aumentarle 5 días. El problema es, ¿cómo hacer eso dentro de la query?

Comment: Ese valor a.DateSubmitted forma parte de cada registro en la tabla _rsform_submissions, creo que estás referenciando algo mal, pues igual deberías obtener primero dicho valor desde la BD y luego si consultar con dicho valor, de lo contrario estarías haciendo una especie de referencia infinita.

Comment: Te hice caso con eso de que quizá estaba referenciando algo mal. Así que terminé haciendo 2 queries, una que inicialmente obtenga los IDs que me interesan, y otra que recupere la información de los IDs recuperados anteriormente. Muchas gracias por tu idea, así salí adelante. Gracias nuevamente!